# is DynamoDB good for time series data? (market stock price example)

Tags: time-series, amazon-dynamodb

Is DynamoDB a good option (or it has some advantages over normal SQL) for saving time series like stock price data?
At first I thought could be good, because of the amount of data, and because we don't need to update or process it.

The problem is normally the timestamp will be the primary key, but if I do that then I cannot search by range with DynamoDB right?
From the official docs they recommend this weird thing:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html
Basically using the "day date" (Y-m-d) as PK and the hour as sort key.
And then also splitting different days in different tables, and adjusting the read/write thing.
So I'm thinking now is a bad idea to save a time series in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

About a year ago i implemented a fairly complex system for storing/accessing time-series using DDB as its underlying storage. To make things concrete let's say you want to store weather-related data. There are several metrics you are interested at ("temprature", "humidity", etc.) and there are several physical locations from which you collect the data (let's assume it is cities: "nyc", "san-francisco", "london", etc.)

I used `<location>-<metric>` as the partition key (e.g., `"nyc.temprature"`, `"london.humidity"`) and the timestamp (seconds since epoch) as the sort key. This resulted in items such as:

```
{name: 'nyc.temperature', timestamp: 1564617785, value: 35.1}
{name: 'nyc.temperature', timestamp: 1564617786, value: 35.2}
{name: 'nyc.temperature', timestamp: 1564617788, value: 35.1}
{name: 'nyc.humidity', timestamp: 1564617786, value: 0.61}
{name: 'nyc.humidity', timestamp: 1564617788, value: 0.61}
{name: 'nyc.humidity', timestamp: 1564617791, value: 0.62}
{name: 'london.temperature', timestamp: 1564617785, value: 33.8}
{name: 'london.temperature', timestamp: 1564617786, value: 33.8}
{name: 'london.temperature', timestamp: 1564617788, value: 33.9}
{name: 'london.humidity', timestamp: 1564617786, value: 0.11}
{name: 'london.humidity', timestamp: 1564617788, value: 0.12}
{name: 'london.humidity', timestamp: 1564617791, value: 0.12}
```

This allowed me to efficiently get all temperature values at any given location for any given time period (which a typical use case for reading time-series data): it was a simple DDB query with `KeyConditionExpression` set to `"#name = :v1 AND #timestamp BETWEEN :v2 and :v3"`

### Further details

To the best of my knowledge, the guideline of spreading the writes across partitions no longer needs to be followed. This is due to the introduction of [adaptive capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-partitions-adaptive). As noted in the title of [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/), "what you know about DynamoDB might be outdated", adaptive capacity dramatically changes the way one needs to think about spreading the keys across partitions. To double check, I also posted a [question on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pembleton/status/1169153374568243200) and got a similar reply.

My guess is that AWS did not update many of their documentation pages. That's why you still see pages such as this [Using Write Sharding to Distribute Workloads Evenly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html)

However, even in the "old" (pre-adaptive capacity) mode you can get a quite far even if you don't shard your writes. Here's why:

As long as your table size < 10GB you will have one partition so sharding will not spread your writes across partitions. Once your table size exceeds 10GB and a new partition is created for you, you will need to buy more capacity. If you don't buy more capacity you'll start seeing throttling errors so you will notice that. At that point (which, according to the data you provided, will be somewhere between 2.5 to 5 months from your starting point) you'll have better understanding of your usage pattern and will be able to make a more knowledgeable decision about the sharding scheme that best fits your needs (yes, you may need to but some temporary capacity to prevent those errors. Alternatively, you can monitor the size of your table and start the sharding preemptively).

For instance, if what you have is mostly writes and only occasional reads (this is typical in many time-series-based applications) then you can create a single table for your writes. This table will not grow beyond 10GB so you do not need to worry about splitting your keys in it. Once day you can move the data from this table to one of X several tables (say, sharded by the current date % X). During that process you can condense the data (collapse several items into one larger item) which may result in more compact footprint (thus requiring reduced capacity). It is possible that you can even move it to S3 instead of a different table. Anyhow, you'll probably have better knowledge about your read pattern then, thus allowing you to design an optimal read solution.

Comment: But then how to decide the "level" of the partition. Suppose I want to save only temperature and only in London in your example. Then I will have only one partition for all the table (london.temperature), and what is the sense of having only one partition key?

Comment: If you're worried about capacity and "hot partitions" then please note that this is no longer a concern due to adaptive capacity. See: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/

Comment: But then why is important to split it in different partition keys? I'm going to search always by date range, never get just one time element. In your example, what happen if we have only one city and only temperature? you will use the same structure? all the items will have the same partition key then? (official example uses a different approach, they use the "day" as partition key and "hour" as sort key)

Comment: BTW, what's the volume of data you are expecting? in other words, in 6 months time, what do you predict the size of the table (say in MB or GB) to be ?

Comment: I guess between 2 and 4 GB per month

Comment: @Enrique added additional details and rationale to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on how you plan to access the data.

DynamoDB is flexible in how you store the data, but inflexible in how you access it (Inexpensive query, vs. expensive Scan operation).

Whereas, SQL is inflexible in how you store the data (you must declare schema first), but powerful in how you access that data (SQL queries).

If you were to use DynamoDb you need to consider your primary key: { partition key + sort key }. How should the data be grouped into partitions? The answer to that question determines your partition key. `YYYY-MM-DD` is probably a good answer. Secondly, how should that data be sorted. By time of course, so the sort key should be `HH:MM:SS`. Or even a `Date` object if you don't mind working with millisecond timestamps or your application can ingest the timestamps.

With that primary key, you can then Query by Date, sorted by time. You can use comparison operators such as Less-than, Greater-than, and Between to select a date range and or time range.

Looking at that article, they follow the same principle. However, I would ignore the part about provisioning multiple tables, and instead just enable On-Demand provisioning. This takes out the guesswork of provisioning read and write units and you simply pay for what you use.

All that to say, DynamoDb can work well for time series data, and can be much faster at querying the data, but you need to carefully consider how you need to access it.